# How do I get realtime keyboard input in Python?

Tags: python, api, input, raw-input, text-based

Is this possible? Every answer I have looked at isn't what I want. What I do though is something like in `omega-rpg` (which is an awesome little text-based debian rpg), but in Python instead of C. I have poked around and found some things, but nothing that's relevant to what I'm doing. Is it just easier to use `raw_input()` / `input`, or would it be more efficient to use some kind of API for doing so?

TO CLEAR UP:

I need a system of realtime keyboard input in Python, but I don't know whether it's easier to use an API or just `raw_input() / input()`. If it IS better to use an API, which is the best one for a beginner-level programmer to use?

EXTRA:

Any solution will be used in a TEXT-BASED GAME! Keep that in mind when answering, please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think using raw_input() in a while loop  is an acceptable solution.

You could also look into something like [pygame](http://www.pygame.org) which would handle the main game loop for you and also offers input handling.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows you can use the [`msvcrt`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/msvcrt.html#console-i-o) module. Specifically, look at `kbhit` to check whether a key is waiting to be read and `getch` to read a key press. The user does not need to press `enter` for the key presses to be made available to your program.

Comment: I'd rather have something that's cross-compatible, but thanks for the answer, I'll keep that in mind C:

Answer (score 0):

You could look into [PyHook](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/pyhook/index.php?title=Main_Page). It provides callbacks for reading mouse and keyboard events.