# Python real-time keyboard input

Tags: python, io, real-time, keyboard-events

I am not looking for `input()` or `raw_input()`.  I am looking for what sounds like is available in the msvcrt module, specifically `msvcrt.kbhit()` and `msvcrt.getch()`, but am unable to get it working.

I tried example 1, here:

http://effbot.org/librarybook/msvcrt.htm

and the chosen answer here:

[Python Windows `msvcrt.getch()` only detects every 3rd keypress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22365473/python-windows-msvcrt-getch-only-detects-every-3rd-keypress)

both of which put me into infinite loops from which I am unable to escape by pressing 'esc' and 'q' respectively.

```
import msvcrt
while True:
    pressedKey = msvcrt.getch()
    if pressedKey == 'x':    
       break
```

I would like to avoid downloading and installing new modules, like pyhook suggested below, if possible:

[How do I get realtime keyboard input in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13694873/how-do-i-get-realtime-keyboard-input-in-python)

Comment: Please include a snippet of the code that isn't working as you expect.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer here: [Python kbhit() problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18672923/python-kbhit-problems)

Basically, you need to run the program from a console window instead of from the IDE (Python in my case).